# Fetch Facebook Non App User Friends in Graph API 2.1 or Facebook SDK 4.0 (PHP)

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, fetch, resultset

I am trying to fetch facebook friends using 'me/taggable_friends' , but it returning even those who are registered on app.
Is there any way to fetch only those friends who are not using app ??

I am using code :

```
        $session = new FacebookSession($_SESSION['facebookToken']);
        try {               
            if ( !$session->validate() ) {
                $session = null;                                          
            }else{
                $param = $id.'/taggable_friends?limit=120&fields=picture.width(300).height(300),id,name';
                $request = new FacebookRequest(
                          $session,
                          'GET',
                          $param
                    );
                $response = $request->execute();
                while($response){                           
                    $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();

                    foreach($graphObject['data'] as $index => $value){

                        $taggable_friends[] = array(
                                    'id' => $value->id,
                                    'name' => $value->name,
                                    'image' => $value->picture->data->url                                   
                        );                                  
                    }

                    if($response->getRequestForNextPage() != null){
                        $response = $response->getRequestForNextPage()->execute();
                        continue;
                    }else{
                        break;
                    }                       
                }                       
            }
            return $taggable_friends;
        }catch ( Exception $e ) {}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code that you are using to do the query as otherwise there is no way for people to troubleshoot your problem. See [how to ask a good question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).